# Scanning in text into a structure

Tags: c, input, text

I have a unknown amount of lines, such as the following text:

> dog 2 4 2 biscuits wet
>
> cat 5 4 4 biscuits wet dry whiskers
>
> bird 1 2 7 birdseed peanuts bread oats worms insects crackers

I need to feed this into a struct, such as

```
struct animal
{
    char animalName[10];
    int age;
    int numberOfLegs;
    int favoriteFoodAmount;
    //*Some way to store favorite foods*
}
```

The last number defines how many favorite foods there are.
I need to be able to store favorite foods. I assume the way to do this would be via an array of char arrays but I have no idea how to do this, or how to implement reading in that text.

Could anyone please give me some pointers on how to do this?

Comment: "some pointers on how to do this" First define the problem more: Max number of foods item? (unlimited is unreasonable - there is always a limiting factor), Max length of the food name?  Can   food/animal names include spaces and if so how to encode?  A direct start is to post what you have tried. "I have no idea" does not engender support.  It not interested in showing what you have tried, then this is simple a request for code and is off topic here.

Comment: actually you may have theoretically unlimited (limited by your memory) number of favorite foods if you use pointers. i tried to give a solution to your problem but while i am fixing bugs i fell asleep and when i woke up the code was gone due to hibernation. if you cannot find the solution yourself with pointers mention me from here. i will give a solution. hint: use char** for favorite foods. use realloc to increase size when needed. if you need some simple illustration on double pointer just tell me.

Comment: and lastly use getchar() for getting the favorite foods since their size is unknown. again use allocate on char* pointer array.